# How do I optimize the regex for finding dates in format day/month/year?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently going through the Automate The Boring Stuff book and this is the first practical question from chapter 7:

> Write a regular expression that can detect dates in the DD/MM/YYYY format. Assume that the days range from 01 to 31, the months range from 01 to 12, and the years range from 1000 to 2999. Note that if the day or month is a single digit, it’ll have a leading zero.

I have come up with this regex but I am sure it could be much simpler than this atrocity:

```
r"^((([0-2]{1})\d{1})|([3][0,1]))\/(([0]{1}\d{1})|([1][0-2]))\/([1,2]\d{3})$"
```

Comment: I would not encode the range inside the regex, just check it afterwards. Then it's simply `r'^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$'`.

Comment: What if you instead exclude the unwanted part of the range like this [^32-99] instead of defining the actual range.

Comment: @Meto Square brackets do not see range in this way. Here is what regex101 says: 3 matches the character 3 literally (case sensitive)
1-9 a single character in the range between 1 (index 49) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
9 matches the character 9 literally (case sensitive)

Comment: @Meto: then it would stop working altogether. GREP does not do computations. Your expression means "not one of the following set of characters: `23456789`" (it contains some duplicates but these will be ironed out).

Comment: @Austin That's exactly what I'm saying: use the regex to parse, then use additional code to check the ranges. Much simpler and more readable than trying to cram everything into a monster regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are vastly over-specifying with your expression.

You don't need `{1}` after `[0-2]` as it already defaults to matching a single character; it's the very definition of `[...]`. Similarly, `[3]` is not necessary; a single character `3` matches as well.

`[0,1]` is an error as it will match any of the single characters `0`, `,`, or `1` – that comma should not be there.

Inside a parenthesized group you don't need to add more parentheses when using an OR `|` bar: `((([0-2])\d)|([3][01]))` can just be `([0-2]\d|3[01])`. The end part does not need parentheses either.

You don't need to escape the `/` character.

With these changes, you end up with

```
r"^([0-2]\d|3[01])/(0\d|1[0-2])/[12]\d{3}$"
```

However: it also matches `00/00/2020`, because the `\d` in `[0-2]\d` (days) and `0\d` (months) may be a zero as well. To fix, change `\d` to `[1-9]`:

```
r"^([0-2][1-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/[12]\d{3}$"
```

But this still matches non-existent dates, such as `31/04/2020` (April 31st) and `30/02/2020` (February 30th). A more insidious case is `29/02/2019` (February 29th **2019**).

It is possible to weed out bad day numbers for a series of months, but ultimately you are going to run into problems with the leap years. This still can be 'solved' with a pure regular expression but will necessarily contain a long, long list of leap year values.

Let's take a close look at the problem statement again:

> **Assume** that the days range from 01 to 31, the months range from 01 to 12, and the years range from 1000 to 2999. Note that if the day or month is a single digit, it’ll have a leading zero.

So all it *really* needs is this:

```
r"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$"
```

because *validating* the date is not asked for. That is, your code *validates* that the day part, for example, is not `99` – but you may *assume* that this never happens!

Per the above, validating a date is best done with actual code, and not with a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! I just wanted to challenge myself and see if it was possible to validate the dates in a simple single regex. Concerning the leap years and April, June, Sept, Nov, that is the second part of the task and it has to be done without the use of regex.

Answer (score -1):

The "atrocity" works, and is probably quite efficient, too. Making *readable* code would probably entail something like what @Thomas suggested - extract the 2, 2, 4 digit numbers, and range-check afterwards.

The exercise you are trying to solve, though, is one about regular expressions, so I guess the atrocity really is your answer. In practical cases, I would have used it, but made sure to document what I was doing, probably using a variable to store the regex:

```
date_extract_re = re.compile("r"^((([0-2]{1})\d{1})|([3][0,1]))\/(([0]{1}\d{1})|([1][0-2]))\/([1,2]\d{3})$")
```

Or even a code comment to say what I was doing.